# "[__array_observer__: ModifyArrayObserver]" when iterating over an array

Tags: javascript, aurelia

First question here so let me know if I don't include everything that is needed.

I have an array callede this.tickets that is being stored in my constructor like the following:

```
  constructor(TicketService) {
    this.ticketService = TicketService;
    this.customers;
    this.tickets = [];
    this.status = false;
  }
```

I have a function that makes an api call and pushes the response data in one at a time after checking if the data exists in my local DB.

```
  setTickets () {
     this.customers.forEach(data => {
      var acctName = encodeURIComponent(data.accountname);
      this.ticketService.getTicketByAccount(acctName).then(resp => {
        if (resp.data.accountname == data.accountname) {
          this.tickets.push(resp.data)
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Afterwards I am trying to iterate over the array in a seperate function:

```
  getZendeskTicketStatus () {
    console.log(this.tickets)
    console.log("this is the arrys length: " + this.tickets.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tickets.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.tickets[i])
    }
  }
```

I am getting the following in response:

```
[__array_observer__: ModifyArrayObserver]
this is the arrys length: 0
```

I am calling each of these functions in a promise so they happen in order.

```
    activate() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var customerPromise = this.setCustomers();
        resolve(customerPromise);
        console.log("First")
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Second")
        this.setTickets();
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Third")
        this.createTicketsInDb();
        this.getZendeskTicketStatus();
      })
  }
```

I don't understand what this array_observer is or how I can iterate over this array successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is resp.data , can you provide the sameple data?

Comment: resp.data looks like the following: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zphmMyWHkCKGCgQQMnGcOyJjPNJ_f5oE/view)

Comment: try calling getZendeskTicketStatus from inside of setTicket , put it after you push the data

Comment: The loops works if called inside of setTicket, any idea why though? I'm not sure I understand why it works there and not in a separate function.

Comment: so basically getZendeskTicket is getting called before you get the response

Comment: I'm not sure how that is possible if I am calling getZendTicketStatus in the third phase of a promise like the following. Could you elaborate a little further?  I added the promise to my main post.

Comment: i just posted an answer , it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to understand this example, hope it will clarify 
so if i am calling setTicket does not mean it going to wait for the response .
so to make setTickets to wait for the response i did this modification

```
setTickets () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.customers.forEach(data => {
            var acctName = encodeURIComponent(data.accountname);
            this.ticketService.getTicketByAccount(acctName).then(resp => {
              if (resp.data.accountname == data.accountname) {
                this.tickets.push(resp.data)
              }
              resolve();
            })
          })
    })

 }
```

now ask the calling function to wait for the response

```
activate() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var customerPromise = this.setCustomers();
        resolve(customerPromise);
        console.log("First")
    }).then(async () => {
        console.log("Second");
        //dont skip it till the time you get the response
     await  this.setTickets();
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Third");
         this.createTicketsInDb();
this.getZendeskTicketStatus();
    })
}
```

Hope this clarifies.